# Why do some files not auto publish with the rest of the project?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013

There are a handful of files in my project that do not auto publish with the rest of my project to IIS when there are changes. I have to manually right-click on those files and publish them individually.

I am pretty sure I have done something to cause this because it appears that all of the files that do this have a check-mark next to the file (see `layout.cshtml` in the image below). What have I done, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: How are you publishing them?  The checkmark next to a file means you have checked it out from source control.  If you are publishing from your source control repository, you'd need to right click on the file and check it in before the updates will push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set file Build Action to Content, right Mouse click on file and select Properties in Solution Explorer. Like this:

[image]